# Can't connect a remote Neo4j server

Tags: java, neo4j

This code works for localhost connection. However, when I connect to a remote machine with bolt with another port, I received the following error:

```
Feb 20, 2018 12:34:51 PM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
INFO: Driver instance org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver@20322d26 created
Feb 20, 2018 12:34:52 PM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
INFO: Closing connection pool towards xxx
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 485454502f312e312034303020496c6c6567616c2063686172616374657220307831360d0a436f6e74656e742d4c656e6774683a20300d0a436f6e6e656374696f6e3a20636c6f73650d0a5365727665723a204a6574747928392e322e32322e763230313730363036290d0a0d0a
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1106)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code:

```
public class TestDriver implements AutoCloseable
{
    private final Driver driver;

    public TestDriver( String uri, String user, String password )
    {
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri, AuthTokens.basic( user, password ) );
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception
    {
        driver.close();
    }

    public void query() throws Exception
    {

        try ( Session session = driver.session() )
        {

            StatementResult result = session.run("match(n) return n");

            while (result.hasNext())
            {
                Record record = result.next();
                List<Value> values = record.values();
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String... args ) throws Exception
    {

            TestDriver driver = new TestDriver( "bolt://localhost:7687/", "neo4j", "test" );
            driver.query();
    }
}
```

Comment: your example is configure to use a local Neo4j. Or from what I understand, it's working on a local Neo4j. Can give us the example for the remote (or just the bolt uri)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Neo4j to accept remote connections.

See: [Remote connection to Neo4j server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220526/remote-connection-to-neo4j-server)